# react js myfn is not a function when called from a button

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I've just started learning about react js and this is my first react js app. I'm using api to fetch the data. so far it works, but now I want to add a search keyword to the function that is acquired from a search bar component.

here's my code:

SearchBar.js

```
const SearchBar = ({ getUsers }) => {
  return (
    <div className="is-flex flex-align-items-center mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="query" className="input search-input" placeholder="search keyword"/>
      <Button className="search-btn ps-3 pe-3" 
      onClick={() => getUsers(document.querySelector('#query').value)}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

MasterUser.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";

const MasterUser = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  const getUsers = async (query='') => {
    console.log('get users', query);
    try {
      let myurl = 'http://localhost:8080/users';
      const response = await fetch(myurl);
      const data = await response.json();
      setUsers(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.getMessage());
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar onClick={getUsers}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

when the app loads, the console log says `get users <empty string>` and it returns all the users as expected, but when I clicked on the search button (magnifyingGlass) it gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: getUsers is not a function`.

any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <SearchBar onClick={getUsers}/>
```

You have named the prop `onClick` not `getUsers`. That's why you get that error.

---

Yeah, accessing dom element value using selectors (e.g. `document.querySelector('#query').value`) is also not typical react. Read about [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) form elements (save form element value in state).

Comment: yeah I still don't really understand how `react` and `state` works.. that's why I used that _dirty_ workaround

Answer (score 1):

Make your searchBar component more *reactive* like so

```
const SearchBar = ({ getUsers }) => {
const [searchValue,setSearchValue]=useState('');
  return (
    <div className="is-flex flex-align-items-center mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="query" className="input search-input" placeholder="search keyword" value={searchValue} onChange={(e)=>setSearchValue(e.target.value)}/>
      <Button className="search-btn ps-3 pe-3" 
      onClick={() => getUsers(searchValue)}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you. your suggestions on making my code more _reactive_ is nice but unfortunately it didn't help with the actual question so I didn't choose your answer as the accepted answer